# File names do not show in shared files using Ubuntu 20.04 Media Sharing

Tags: 20.04, dlna, upnp, rygel

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 and enabled Media Sharing. My TV and other devices see the shared media and plays them well when I try. However, I cannot see the filename, only some stuff which I think part of the metadata of the files. For example, things like `SDH` or `English, Dutch` or something like that. The following picture shows some these files when I browse them on the VLC Player:

[image: The files as seen from the client]

I tried to find a soluion and found out that the DLNA server is something called Rygel. I tried the following: I edited`rygel.conf` under `~/.config/`, changed `extract-metadata` to `false`. I, then deleted the `media-export.db` file under `~/.cache/rygel/`. Disabled and then enabled the Media Sharing. It did not make a difference.

Is there anything I am missing? I only want to see filenames, I don't care about metadata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the cause of the issue but not unfortunately no solution - https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-base/-/issues/598. I guess we will  need to wait till they fix this bug. From the bug descritption:
"Between versions 1.14 and 1.16, there has been a change either in gst-discoverer itself or in some underlying part of gstreamer, which causes gst-discoverer to now leak title tags from subtitle tracks into "main" title track, which in turn causes problems in applications that rely on gst-discoverer."

Answer (score 2):

I have a workaraound for this using mkvpropedit -s to set the title to the same as the filename from a bash script, need to install mkvtoolnix package first. it isn't pretty but worked for me. after trying to remove the metadata and it just appearing back again :(

```bsh
    #!/bin/bash
    for file in /home/ivor/Videos/foldername/*.mkv
    do
        newtitle=${file##*/}
        echo $newtitle
        mkvpropedit "$file" -s title="$newtitle"
    done
```